# What does 行文至此 mean in 行文至此，北京市职业介绍部门传来令人欣喜的消息……?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

> **行文至此**，北京市职业介绍部门传来令人欣喜的消息：在招聘的85名保洁员中，有50人是北京人。
> <sub>Short Term Reading Chinese (2nd edition): Advanced; [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Yk0.jpg) ([alternative site](https://i.ibb.co/FKjSwJ8/50826325.jpg))</sub>

I'm confused about why this sentence from my textbook begins with 行文至此.

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%A1%8C%E6%96%87): 行文 (xíng​wén​) writing style (formal) / to send an official written communication
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%87%B3%E6%AD%A4): 至此 (zhì​cǐ​) up until now / so far

Judging from the above, 行文 seems illogical (missing definition?).  And 至此 is just another way of saying 至今.

**Question**: What does 行文至此 mean in 行文至此，北京市职业介绍部门传来令人欣喜的消息……?

Comment: At the very moment when I am writing this, or it is a coincidence when I am about to say it, the thing I desire happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

行文至此: At the time of writing, Thus far,

行文：Probably a reference to:

行笔xíng bǐ

1. 中国书法的用笔方法，
   A Chinese calligraphy style of using the brush,
   指笔锋在纸上的运转动作，
   refers to the way of moving the tip of the brush on the paper,
   也称运笔。
   aka wield (the) brush.
   语本汉蔡邕《九势》:
   etymology: Han Dynasty Cai Yong (133-192) <9 forms>
   "令笔心常在点画中行。
   "Let the brush middle always follow the stroke.
   " 宋代魏泰《东轩笔录》：
   "Song Dynasty Wei Tai 
   “近世沈辽最善行笔。”
   "(In the) Modern world Shen Liao (is the) best writer. (best at writing (xingbi))

2.指行文。
Refers to writing style

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the photo posted by OP. But 行文至此 usually means ***till now (the very point of this writing)***.

行文 is like *walking through an article*. It's a vivid/traditional way to say 写文章.

Answer (score 1):

文章**寫**到這裡 - 行(寫)文(文章)至(到)此(這裡). [行文](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A1%8C%E6%96%87)

"行", actually means "走", here, it should be interpreted as "寫", as it describes the act of "writing". A modern equivalent of 行文至此 is "走筆至此".

**Content:** The writer was writing an article about the employment condition of the native Pekinese, and at some point before finishing, he heard the good news about.... So "**writing up to this point**, a good news has arrived...."

Answer (score 1):

**行文至此**：Before we break it down, this combination of 4 characters roughly means **"up to this point of writing"** in English.

> Judging from the above, 行文 seems illogical (missing definition?). And
> 至此 is just another way of saying 至今.

**至此** is not another way of saying 至今。In the context of writing:

- 至：till / to (a destination)
- 此：here / (at) this point
- 至此："to this point"

---

**行文**，in the context of writing:

- 行：(something) walk / walk (something) / make something move
- 文：article / writing (the thing that you're writing)
- 行文："Writing ..." (article or sentence etc)

**[abstract]** Imagine the exact moment when you're holding a pen (or with a pen in mind) and writing (something, maybe a sentence).

---

Extra:

You may have seen the usage like "**行文**如流水", the meaning is then fairly straight forward.